# SAP Crystal Report Visual Studio 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How can the parameter prompt in SAP Crystal Report be disabled? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
My Code is:

```
{
    NPB.Report.CrLetter objCrLetter = new NPB.Report.CrLetter();
    NPB.Report.frmViewer objView = new NPB.Report.frmViewer();


    private void btnGenerateLetters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["LetterDate"].DefaultValues.AddValue(dtpLetterDate.Value.ToShortTimeString());
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["Salutation"].DefaultValues.AddValue(cboboxSalutation.Text);
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["Address"].DefaultValues.AddValue("2");
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["City"].DefaultValues.AddValue("3");
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["State"].DefaultValues.AddValue("4");
        objCrLetter.ParameterFields["ZipCode"].DefaultValues.AddValue("5");
        objView.crViewer.ReportSource = objCrLetter;
        objView.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably change your code so that for each Parameter in the Crystal Report would clear the current & default values then pass in the correct value.

So you need to do something like this for each parameter:

```
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDV = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramDV.Value = "Parameter Value";
objCrLetter.ParameterFields["@ParameterName"].CurrentValues.Clear();
objCrLetter.ParameterFields["@ParameterName"].DefaultValues.Clear();
objCrLetter.ParameterFields["@ParameterName"].CurrentValues.Add(paramDV);
```

This should prevent the Parameter Prompt from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

This answers are almost perfect, but, You should pay attention to the when setting de data source.

This setting should happens before you set the parameters.